# Trying to translate some initialisation in objective C to swift 3.0

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization, init

iOS 10.10 Swift 3.0

I got this in objective C and I want to port it across to swift 3.0.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    [self setupDefaultAttributes];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    [self setupDefaultAttributes];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I think I'm almost there, but I am struggling to figure the self reference?

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupDefaultAttributes()
}

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupDefaultAttributes()
}
```

Comment: It looks good to me. What error are you getting?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Obj-C (over half a decade and then not professionally), but I believe this is 100% correct. IIRC, in Obj-C initializers explicitly *return* the object being allocated (do they still need that anymore?) and set up, but in Swift you do not. I guess that's implicit?

Comment: initializers in Objective-C and Swift don't have much in common. While in objective-c they are just normal method and called something started with init… by convention, initialisers in swift aren't even methods at all. They don't return anything. Both have certain rules. in objective-c by convention, in Swift enforced by the compiler. make sure you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html